# Right-aligning the middle column with alignat

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignat

I can accomplish what I want by manual spacing with `align`:

```
\begin{align*}
    o(\xi_n^k) \,&|\, r \\
    \Leftrightarrow \:\:\:\:\, \frac{n}{k} \,&\Big|\, \frac{n}{|\mathcal{O}|} \\
    \Leftrightarrow \:\: |\mathcal{O}| \,&|\, k
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Here's my attempt with `alignat`:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & o(\xi_n^k) \,&&|\, r \\
    \Leftrightarrow\, & \frac{n}{k} \,&&\Big|\, \frac{n}{|\mathcal{O}|} \\
    \Leftrightarrow\, & |\mathcal{O}| \,&&|\, k
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

I need the middle column to align to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to have understood your request. Here I have used the enviroment `alignat` differently of your code. You see if it is the desidered output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}

\texttt{This is your version:}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & o(\xi_n^k) \,&&|\, r \\
    \Leftrightarrow\, & \frac{n}{k} \,&&\Big|\, \frac{n}{|\mathcal{O}|} \\
    \Leftrightarrow\, & |\mathcal{O}| \,&&|\, k
\end{alignat*}


\texttt{This is my version:}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
     &&    o(\xi_n^k) &|\, r\\
     \Leftrightarrow &&  \frac{n}{k} & \Big|\,\frac{n}{|\mathcal{O}|}\\
     \Leftrightarrow && |\mathcal{O}|\, & |\,k
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]